# vba to force close on protected project

Tags: excel, vba

We use this to force close vba projects that stay open after closing the Excel workbook;

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    On Error Resume Next
    If Not (Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible) Then
        Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
        Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

It works fine until you protect the project. Once you protect the project it stays open again even when you close the Excel workbook.

Our only workaround is to periodically close all Excel instances a few times a day to stop the memory error appearing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: VBA Projects cannot stay opened if their file gets closed, because VBA is a part of the workbook. If you close a workbook and its VBA remains open that means your workbook did not close proplerly and you should fix that instead of trying to workaround. • Also note that `.Visible = False` does not close anything but hide. That means it remains open.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` (with no attempt to test for and respond to errors) is already an indication that you are doing something problematic.

Comment: Thanks for your advise!

Comment: @DarrellMee I think you are up the wrong tree. Can you improve ([edit]) your question and add more information about how are your workbooks opened/closed (manually or by code). Because I think this is a [X/Y-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and you asked just the wrong question. Your actual issue is something else, but we need more details on what is actually going on to really help you. • Best would be if you could provide a [mcve] to illustrate your actual issue. Sounds like you got a memory leak somewhere else.

Comment: *"[snip]to stop the memory error appearing."*  What memory error?  There is no mention of one earlier in the question...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding "Set Application.ThisWorkbook = Nothing" after closing in vba?

`Workbooks.Open ThisWorkbook.FullName`

`ThisWorkbook.Close False`

`Set Application.ThisWorkbook = Nothing`

This has helped me with a similar issue in the past of VBA remaining after closing a workbook out.